# Dedekind domain and converse of Krull's principal ideal theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

It is clear that Dedekind domain's all primes other than $(0)$ are maximal. Its dimension must be $\leq 1$. Suppose this domain is not a field. So $\dim=1$. 
So all maximal must be minimal over a principal element.

Here is Krull's principal ideal theorem converse.

Thm: Any prime of height $c$ is minimal over an ideal generated by $c$ elements.

Consider $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Then $m=(3,2+\sqrt{-5})$ is a maximal ideal. One can check this easily by lifting to $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)$.

Q1. This maximal ideal $m$ is generated by 2 elements. Why this maximal ideal is not minimal over itself? $m$'s primary decomposition is itself. So it is minimal over itself.

The reason to ask this question is that $m$ should be minimal over principal ideal rather than $(3,2+\sqrt{-5})$. If $m$ minimal over itself, this says $ht(m)\leq 2$ from Krull PIT. Now converse says $m$ minimal over principal by $m$ having $ht(m)=1$.

Q2. $m$ cannot be minimal over itself and a principal ideal simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $m$ is minimal over itself, but this does not contradict the theorem: it simply says that $m$ is minimal over *a* principal ideal.  And indeed, since $(3) = (3, 1 + \sqrt{-5})(3, 2 + \sqrt{-5})$, $m$ is minimal over the principal ideal $(3)$.

Comment: $m$ is minimal over itself. Why $m$ can be minimal over itself and minimal with respect to $(3)$ at the same time? Minimal means different meaning here? I guess first means minimal over $m$ where the latter means it is the minimal prime of associated prime over $(3)$? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: To say that a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime of an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ means that there is no prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \neq \mathfrak{p}$ with $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$.  $m$ a is minimal prime of $m$, and $m$ is also a minimal prime of $(3)$ (and also of $(2 + \sqrt{-5})$).

Comment: Ah, my dumbness. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this topic is much clearer if you think about it geometrically.  A minimal prime corresponds to a (maximal) irreducible component.  For instance, the ideal $(xy)$ of $k[x,y]$ corresponds to the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes.  Its minimal primes are $(x)$, and $(y)$, corresponding to the $y$- and $x$-axes, which are the irreducible components.  So $(x)$ is a minimal prime of $(xy)$.  $(x)$ is also a minimal prime of itself, since the $y$-axis is already an irreducible variety.